# Expander Header text binding not respecting the string formatter

Tags: wpf, data-binding, expander

I have a WPF Expander in my project. I have applied styles to the expander to change the header colors and whatnot. After doing so, my data is still bound to the Header's content area, but it just binds the raw data and not the formatting I have specified. See the examples below.

```
<Style x:Key="ValkyrieStyleExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
   <!-- Ommiting property setters for brevity -->
   <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
       <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                           Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the actual declaration with the appropriate binding syntax

```
<Expander Style="{StaticResource ValkyrieStyleExpander}" 
           Margin="10,10,0,0" 
           Width="670" 
           Header="{Binding PolicyNumber, StringFormat=Policy {0}}">
</Expander>
```

We I run the app, the header should display "Policy 123456", and before I restyled the expander it did so. But now when I run the app, the header just shows "123456". I am still kind of a babe-in-the-woods when it comes to databinding, so I am not sure really what I need to do to get the new style to show the correct data. Hopefully the answer isn't to add it to the ValkyrieStyleExpender's Header Template style, as that would defeat the purpose of having a style (Not all expanders in the project are for displaying a particular policy)

Comment: Can you please give an example where it works *without* a style (because normally `StringFormat` never should work in a binding for the `Expander.Header` property)? `StringFormat` works only for properties that have type `string`.

Comment: `PolicyNumber` is of type `string`?

Comment: @Rohit, yes the policy number is a string property on the view model.

Comment: @fmunkert, just removed the style declaration from the expander and it worked for me

Comment: Not sure what you edited, @Andy G, but congratulations on a wonderful choice of icon, lol.

Answer (score 1):

`StringFormat` usually does not work when using it within the `Expander.Header` property since the property is [not of type string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.header%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You will need to write your own class derived from `IFormatter` that implements the formatted string you'd actually define in the property. I've researched quite a bit and found no better solution for this issue.

The class may look as follows:

```
public class SomeClass: IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if(format == "n")
        {
            return "This is the formatted string";
        }
        else
        {
            return "this is the non-formatted string";
        }
    }
}
```

And you would use it in your style this way:

```
Setter Property="HeaderStringFormat" Value="n" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? According to the MSDN documentation, `HeaderStringFormat` is ignored if the `HeaderTemplate` property is set (like in the OP's style). (See "Remarks" section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headerstringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @fmunkert No I'm not sure, thanks for pointing this out. If it's really unpossible to do it with a style he might consider giving up the style. Not an elegant solution but though it works.

Comment: @Mostey, you are linking to the German documentation.  The OP is in California and German language documentation may not be very helpful.

Comment: @GayotFow MSDN shows the english translation automatically for me although it is a German link. However, I updated the link.

Comment: Thank you @mostey. I appreciate the thought and research that went into this. From a purist standpoint, I would be weary of a solution that required the view model to change to accommodate the view. Ideally, I would want to keep them both unaware of each other.

Comment: Another solution would be to declare a property in your ViewModel (as string) that returns your formatted string. Then you could bind to that property. I also did that a few times when I had problems with my localization library and StringFormat.

Answer (score 1):

If the string format is not working for you, you can easily implement a **converter**, such as...

```
#region PolicyConverter (ValueConverter)
public class PolicyConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return "Policy " + value.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
#endregion
```

...and then declare it in your **Xaml**...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <pc:PolicyConverter x:Key="PolicyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...and finally reference it in your template.  I did not use (or modify) your **ValkyrieStyleExpander** code.  But to verify the correctness of this approach, I used the following declaration as a functional prototype...

```
    <Expander Name="Expander1">
        <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=Expander1, 
                    Path=DataContext.PolicyNumber, 
                    Converter={StaticResource PolicyConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    </Expander>
```

...and it worked as expected (.net 4.5).  If you needed to evacuate the in-lined templating to a global declaration in your **Xaml**, this would also make a great starting point.

Comment: Hi @Gayot fow, unfortunately I can't specify the exact formatter in the expanders header template as I need to reuse the style on other expanders. But your answer brings to mind another question: namely could I override the style within the specific expander implementing the style? I will have to test that when I get home.